# Is there a way to search among android existing vector icons?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Intellij idea has a list of most used vector icons in "Asset studio", appreciate for filtering icons by category, But how can I search a term among those icons to find it a bit easily?

[image]

Comment: you can explore https://materialdesignicons.com/ for more icons

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot I am using Intellij idea. I edited my question.

Comment: @patzu there is almost no difference between `Idea` and `Android Sudio`. The latter is basically an extension of `Idea IDE` having all of its functionality. Asset Studio in `Idea 2017.2` looks and behaves in exactly the same way as in Studio. Just checked :) Probably your version of `Idea` is old? I suppose this because of license statement difference. In `Idea  2017.2` I see `Apache License 2.0` like on the screenshot from my answer.

Comment: Aha, mine version is 2017.1.5 and no such capability.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what you are using `Android Studio` or `Idea IDE` I suppose you can just start typing while `select icon` window is active.

I am on OS X and it looks a bit different here:
[image]

P.S. The screenshot is from Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2, but Android Studio 2.3 stable has exactly the same asset studio interface.

P.P.S. `Android Studio` is based on `Idea IDE` + `Android plugin`. Asset Studio is available in both of them and works identically. Just Checked.